# Why RDDs is not listed in the spark UI/storage page

Tags: apache-spark, rdd

I am a newbie for Spark.

I installed the Spark 1.3.1 on my mac, and played with it by using spark-shell, here was what I did:

```
scala> val lfile = sc.textFile("/Users/jackzhang/Downloads/ProdPart.txt");
scala> val count = lfile.filter(line => line.contains("XYZ_COW"))
scala> count.count
```

Output

```
res27: Long = 1
```

I also tried to run

```
scala> count.cache
```

It did not work either.

My understanding is that I should get the `count` RDD materialized in the memory (or disk), because I run the `count.count`, and `count` is an `Action` per [Spark Documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/programming-guide.html#actions), and I should be able to see it from http://localhost:4040/storage, am I wrong?

Comment: But is right only is saved when you persist or cache, take a look: https://forums.databricks.com/questions/117/why-is-my-rdd-not-showing-up-in-the-storage-tab-of.html
Now do lfile.cache(), and then count.count, works?

Comment: Thanks, Makoton, it works, I ran count.cache.collect, and it shows up in the page.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As Makoton mentioned, https://forums.databricks.com/questions/117/why-is-my-rdd-not-showing-up-in-the-storage-tab-of.html answered this question.

To see the RDD in the "Storage" tab, here is what I did after reading the post:

```
scala> val cacheCount = count.cache
scala> cacheCount.collect
```

After that, I can see the RDD in the tab, however, I also tried to update the RDD name, by running:

```
scala> cacheCount.setName("Test")
scala> cacheCount.cache
scala> cacheCount.collect
```

The name of the RDD did not get updated. Which means the part of the answer posted in the forum is incorrect.

Comment: After do more research on this topic, I realized that if you run the cacheCount.setName("Test") before scala> cacheCount.collect, you will be able to see the changes, but once you run the scala> cacheCount.collect, you will never be able to change the name of the RDD buy running:scala> cacheCount.setName("Test")
scala> cacheCount.cache
scala> cacheCount.collect

Comment: Is that because of the RDD is immutable?

Comment: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-9044 is logged for updating the RDD name issue.